# ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.compose' with scikit-learn==0.23.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm fully aware of the previous post regarding this error. That issue was with scikit-learn < 0.20. But I'm having scikit-learn `0.23.2` and I've tried uninstall and reinstall `0.22` and `0.23` and I still have this error.

Followup: Although `pip list` told me the scikit-learn version is `0.23.2`, but when I ran `sklearn.__version__`, the real version is `0.18.1`. Why and how to resolve this inconsistency? (Uninstall 0.23.2 didn't work)

Comment: may you try this command: ```pip3 show scikit-learn```?

Comment: @ IThinkImOKAY  with pip3 it showed 0.23.2

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED]

It turned out that my Conda environment has different `sys.path` as my jupyter environment. The jupyter environment used the system env, which is due to the fact that I installed the `ipykernel` like this: `python -m ipykernel install` without use `--user` flag. The correct way should be to do so within the Conda env and run `pip install jupyter`